# How do I set my AWS S3 Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage to public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

According to the [Rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access), I can set the files to be public. However, when I tried it, I get this error:

```
Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`
invalid configuration option `:public'):
```

If I remove the `public: true` in my `storage.yml` file, it works. But then the file itself is private and so my Cloudflare CDN cannot serve it.

```
# config.storage.yml
amazon_dev:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'] %>
  region: us-west-2
  public-read: true
  bucket: xxxxxx
```

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon_dev
```

Also set the AWS S3 to public:
[S3 bucket settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqByP.png)

Can't embed yet so this will be a link.

Thank you,

Comment: I think I've run into the same issue (albeit with DigitalOcean, but it's compatible with S3) and the solution seems to be using s3cmd to iterate through every file in my bucket until they're all public, then I can deploy the `public: true` change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with your AWS settings, not Rails.

When creating a bucket, UNTICK "block all public access":

[image]

See the difference of a public and a private bucket in the dashboard:
[image]

For adding a policy:
[image]

it can be something like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already did that. Editing my question

Comment: When I click on the individual object in S3, it says Access Denied. I literally have to make each object public manually then it works. I need something that will scale. Essentially, when ActiveStorage uploads it, it needs to set it as public-read.

Comment: how do you want public objects to be accessed via your app?

Comment: Got it to work. In addition to allowing it to be public, I set a policy such that everyone can read it. Thank you. I can clean it up later by limiting it to just my CDN.

Comment: Adding a fuller answer in case anyone got here. I added this policy
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"]
    }
  ]
}